# Notation of Fourier Transforms

Tags: soft-question, notation, fourier-transform

Why are there so many different notation formats for the Fourier Transform?

Wikipedia defines it in this way for a function $x(t)$:
$$\hat{f}(k) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)e^{-2\pi i kt}dt$$
However I also see the following

- $F(k)$
- $F(ik)$
- $F(2\pi ik)$
- $F_x(k)$
- $F[x(t)](k)$
- $F_t[x(t)](k)$

There are also many various combinations of the above I haven't mentioned (and also more if you consider angular frequency).  The versions I understand the least are why you would ever include non-variables in the argument ($2\pi i$ for example).

Comment: Fourier transforms are widely used by Mathematicians, Engineers, Physicists, etc. It is impossible to have uniform definitions and notations.

Comment: Never mind Fourier transforms, what about $i$ and $j$!

Comment: Very true, however addition, integration, differentiation, these things are all widely by Mathematicians, Engineers, and Physicists but we have more or less uniform notation there, i don't see that this is the root cause

Comment: there are also different definitions, be careful assuming some definition  when reading some paper or book

Comment: For your last sentence: you should really ask whoever uses such notation.

Comment: The first 3 are abbreviations used when it is clear from the context which variable is transformed whereas the latter 3 are longer and more explicit. Use these when you transform parametric functions to make clear which variables are transformed.

Comment: Actually, there are different notations for integration when it's used to calculate an average or mean in probabilistic contexts.  Then one can use various forms of capital "E", a bar over a variable or expression, or angle brackets.  I've also seen "P" used this way, which is weird but makes sense in some contexts.  I might be forgetting some variants. There are also many different kind of integral notations used with the standard skinny "S", with sets as subscripts, $dx$'s in weird places, $d$ with respect to a measure rather than a variable, and so on. I'm sure that I haven't seen them all.